# What ability modifier, if any, would apply to a firearm attack roll?

Tags: dnd-5e, ability-scores, ranged-attack, attack-roll, firearms

I'm playing D&D 5e, and I'm not sure what ability score applies to firearm attack rolls. (Using the stats from the DM's Guide.)

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [How is firearm damage calculated?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103126/how-is-firearm-damage-calculated)

Comment: Technically speaking, I don't think this is quite a duplicate. The linked question is about rolling the damage of this attack. This question is about the attack roll to hit in the first place. (Although the linked question is definitely related).

Comment: @linksassin I am not seeing that. The question as stated in the linked question was "Is the damage of firearms computed like other ranged weapon attacks? The attacker adds his Dexterity modifier to the damage?" And the heading is "How is firearm damage calculated?" None of those questions concern about the attack roll, just the damage. Or am I missing something?

Comment: As Gandalfmeansme said, the answer is basically the same, but the questions are technically different, so they're not duplicates.

Answer (score 28):

### Dexterity

Every Firearm in the DMG (p. 268) is a Ranged weapon. And the rules state (PHB, p. 194)

> the ability modifier used for a ranged weapon attack is Dexterity.

If the creature using the firearm is proficient with them (up to the DM to determine), then they would also add their proficiency bonus to the roll to hit (but not the roll to damage, which would just add the Dexterity modifier).